# avoid horizontal description to stack on small devices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Bootstrap's [Horizontal description](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-inline-text) is the element I need, but I don't want it to stack on small devices. Is it that possible? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is taken straight from the  [official documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed). 
 You can replace the text `.col-xs-6` given in the example below to your horizontal description.

```
<!-- Columns are always 50% wide, on mobile and desktop -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6</div>
</div>
```